# What's the best way to send a newsletter with PHPMailer?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, privacy

I'm trying to send a newsletter with PHPMailer meanwhile protecting my customers privacy.

At first I set the receiver configuration with `mail->addAddress('customerEmail']);` but I found out that sending it this way, every receiver could see other customer's subscribers E-mail addresses.
I changed the `addAddress` to `mail->addBCC('customerEmail']);` so that it doesn't show every E-Mail address (in fact now it even doesn't show the recipient E-mail address of the customer it's being send to), but this way if anyone wanted to reply to the E-mail, their response would also be sent to the rest of the subscribers...

What is for you the best option to face this problem?

Comment: Loop through every customer and send them the newsletters apart from every customer? example: 10 customers. Loop through your customer table, and let it send the newsletter to every 10 apart?

Comment: Wouldn't that increase the sending time?

Comment: Hm, yeah it might, you could send it around a time like 3/4 am? So it doesn't really affect performance when you have to use the system you're PHPMailer is build on?

Comment: How can you possibly reply to other BCC recipients? Check the generated e-mail source code, they aren't even there!

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Es verdad, pensé que como estaba en una carbon copy aunque fuese oculta al responder el email les llegaría a todos en copia. Sin embargo si lo envío como BCC no hay manera de que aparezca el correo del receptor pero no el del resto. ¿Alguna forma de lograr esto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I was advised, the best way to manage a newsletter is to send the email individually to every customer although it means a slight increase on the sending time. This way you can offer automated unsubscription links and other features that otherwise you couldn't.

In order to achieve that, I just made a simple loop getting the addresses from my db:

```
$sql = "SELECT `email` FROM `emails`";
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();

while ($fila = $statement->fetch()) {
    if(!empty($fila['email'])){
        $mail->addAddress($fila['email']);
        $success = $mail->Send();
        $mail->clearAllRecipients(); //Don't forget this!
    }
}
```

The method `clearAllRecipients();` is very important as it's the one who will clear the last lap recipient so that the 'to' section of the email doesn't show all your newsletter recipients.

Answer (score 1):

Email servers do not use the message headers to deliver messages. When you send an email your email client maintains a conversation* like this:

```
EHLO example.com
MAIL FROM: mail@example.com
RCPT TO: info@example.net, customers@example.org, john@example.com
DATA
From: Me <webmaster@example.com>
To: Customers <whatever@example.com>
Subject: Important info
Dear Blah,

Blah blah.

Regards,
.
```

<sup>(*) It *is* a conversation because it includes server response to each command but I've omitted that part.</sup>

What really counts is the information provided in the specific commands before the `DATA` block. Certainly, most mail tools will create headers to match the addresses in the processing instructions but such headers are for pure informational purposes and they don't need to be identical. In fact that's how Bcc actually works: you instruct your mailer to deliver email to such address but omit it from headers.

So:

- You can do it fast (Bcc and a single message for all)
- You can do it nice (To and one message per recipient)

If you ask for my opinion, it's always nice to know the exact e-mail address to which a newsletter is being sent—many of us have more than one address. And it's actually mandatory to send customised messages if you want to offer automated unsubscription links.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will send a single email for every customer although this means a increase on the sending time.